# How to compare security setting/access rights between 2 SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server

Executing SP to check who is currently logon in the SQL working fine in Development database.But executing same SP in LIVE database only return 1 "runnable" record.

Both databases are reside in same physical SQL server. Had compare 2 database using some external freeware and shareware, can't find any difference especially on "Users and Roles" or "DB Properties".

Appreciate if got any solutions or suggestions.

Thanks to David.Chu.ca for the following store procedure.

```
*======================================================
USE [SAFEQA]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_checkUserID]    Script Date: 12/09/2009 09:11:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_checkUserID] 
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER  
AS 
begin 
DECLARE @retTable TABLE (
 SPID int not null 
 , Status varchar (50) not null 
 , Login varchar (50) not null 
 , HostName varchar (50) not null 
 , BlkBy varchar(50) not null 
 , DBName varchar (50) null 
 , Command varchar (50) not null 
 , CPUTime int not null 
 , DiskIO int not null 
 , LastBatch varchar (50) not null 
 , ProgramName varchar (100) null 
 , SPID2 int not null 
 , REQUESTID INT)

 INSERT INTO @retTable EXEC sp_who2 
   SELECT Status, Login, HostName, DBName, Command, CPUTime, ProgramName -- *  
   FROM @retTable  
   --WHERE Login not like 'sa%' -- if not intereted in sa  
   ORDER BY Login, HostName
END 

*====================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-priviledged accounts can only see their own session from sp_who/sp_who2. In particular, code running under the database scopped impersonation context (EXECUTE As OWNER) will not be able to see any other session.

See [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) for an example how to elevate the database impersonation context to the server (that example is actually exactly about reading the sessions DMVs).

If I'd venture a guess, the difference between production and development is that in production the database SAFEQA is not marked as TRUSTWORTHY.

See also [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Remus Rusanu for the fast reply. 

Actually, it only return 1 record even if running the above SP using SA accounts. When i try to exec sp_who/sp_who2 and it returns all records. 

For the connections string to the database is as shown below is considered marked as TRUSTWORTHY? 

CONSTR=Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=spl-vmsql08;trusted_connection=Yes;Database=SAFEQA

Comment: It doesn't matter who executes the procedure. Please read the link provided.

Comment: To make a database TRUSTWORTHY the sysadmin has to mark it so. Is not a connection string option.

Comment: Hi Remus Rusanu, 

The SP works after i set my database to Trustworthy. 
Thank you very much of your advice!